# Webrtc is not receiving video and audio at the same time

Tags: javascript, webrtc

For me webrtc is working well.But It is only receiving video or audio.I am not being able to receive both audio and video at a time.If I add the line written bellow on the receiver side It will receive audio.

```
peer.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: "recvonly" })
```

On the other hand if I don't add this line it will not receive any audio.I have no issue with audio direction.But I can only add audio or video.Adding both is not working.Sorry for my bad english.